# Permutation acting on Edges induced by Permutation acting on Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, symmetric-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, direct-product

From "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" by Christoph M. Hoffmann

> Let $X = (V,E)$ be a graph with vertex set $ V = \{1,2..... n \} $.
>   The automorphism  group $Aut(X)$ of $X$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. 
>   Weconstruct a new representation  for $S_n$ by letting the group act on
>   the set of all unordered pairs  $(i,j)$; 
>   $ 1 \leq  i,j \leq  n, i \neq j$. The group isomorphism accomplishing this is defined by the
>   association of $\pi$ in $S_n$  with a permutation  $\psi$ of the new
>   permutation domain, where
>   $(i,j)^{\psi} = (i^{\pi},j^{\pi})$
>   Let $S_n'$ denote $S_n$ acting on this new permutation  domain. Note
>   that $S_n$ is generated by the two permutations $\alpha = (1,2)$, and
>   $\beta = (1,2 .... , n)$. Thus we also have generators for $S_n'$ .
>   Let $E$ be the set of non-edges of $X$, that is, the unordered pair
>   $(i,j)$ is in $ E$ iff $(i,j)$ is not in $\bar E$. Let 
>   $T = Sym(E)×Sym(\bar E)$ be the direct product of $Sym(E)$ and
>    $Sym(\bar E)$. Note that $T$ is generated by four permutations  which we know.
>   We claim the following
>
> **Theorem 7**
>
> Let $X = (V,E)$ be a graph with vertex set $V = \{1,2 ..... n \}$.
>   Then $Aut(X)$  is isomorphic to the intersection of $S_n'$ with 
>   $T =Sym(E) \times Sym(\bar E)$.
>   **Proof:** Let $A = Aut(X)$ be the automorphism group of $X, A'$ the isomorphic >group obtained by letting $A$ act on the set of all
>   unordered vertex  pairs. Let $\alpha \in A $ be an automorphism,
>   $\alpha'$ the corresponding element in $A'$. Since $\alpha$  is a
>   vertex permutation, $\alpha'$ is an element of $S_n'$. Since $\alpha$
>   maps edges into edges and nonedges into nonedges, $\alpha'$ is also in
>   $T$. Conversely, let $\alpha'$ be in $S_n' \cap T$. Since $\alpha' \in  S_n'$
>   , there is an associated vertex permutation in $S_n$. Since
>    $\alpha' \in T$, the corresponding vertex permutation  maps edges into
>   edges and nonedges into nonedges, hence it is an automorphism.
>   Therefore, $A' = S_n' \cap T$ .

I don't understand the the passage-

> We construct a new representation  for $S_n$ by letting the group act on
>   the set of all unordered pairs  $(i,j)$; 
>   $ 1 \leq  i,j \leq  n, i \neq j$.

Unordered pairs mean all possible non-edges and edges of $X$.

> The group isomorphism accomplishing this is defined by the
>   association of $\pi$ in $S_n$  with a permutation  $\psi$ of the new
>   permutation domain, where
>   $(i,j)^{\psi} = (i^{\pi},j^{\pi})$.

This means edge/non-edge $(i,j)$ is mapped to $(i,j)^{\psi}$ (by permutation $\psi$)when vertices $i^{},j^{}$ are to mapped to $i^{\pi},j^{\pi}$ (by permuation $\pi$)

> Let $S_n'$ denote $S_n$ acting on this new permutation  domain.

**Does this mean $S_n'$ is the symmetric group of all edges and non edges of $X$?**

In that case it should be$S_{{n}\choose{2}}'$ instead of $S_n'$ .

Also , **is $A'=T \leq S_n'$ ?** since

> Since $\alpha$ maps edges into edges and non-edges into non-edges, 
>   $\alpha'$ is also in$T$.

Besides, what is the significance of the theorem? I really don't get it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a lot not to understand in even the first paragraph. I might be able to explain part of it.

Suppose $G$ is a group of automorphisms of a graph $X=(V,E)$. Then $G$ is a permutation group acting on $V$. If we think about we see that, for each $k\ge1$, our group $G$ will permute the set $\binom{V}{k}$ of all subsets of $V$. Hence we have a homomorphism from the permutation group $G$ to a permutation group $H$ acting on $\binom{V}{k}$, for each $k$. [The term
"homomorphism" is being abused here, there is extra structure that must be preserved.]

Often $G$ and $H$ will be isomorphic as abstract groups. (But if $k=2$ and $X=K_2$, there are not.)

Assume now that $k=2$. Then $H$ acts on the unordered pairs of vertices of $X$. If $X$ is neither complete nor empty, the set of unordered pairs can partitioned into two non-empty cells $E$ and $\bar{E}$, where $E=E(X)$ and $\bar{E}=E(\bar{X})$. Both $E$ and $\bar{E}$ are unions of orbits
of $H$, they are $H$-invariant.

If $H$ is a permutation group on a set $S$ and this set is the disjoint union of two $H$-invariant subsets $C$ and $D$, then $H$ can be expressed as subgroup of the direct product of two permutation groups, namely the restrictions of $H$ to $C$ and $D$ respectively. Therefore $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(C)\times\mathrm{Sym}(D)$.